# Symfony 2 Installation Issue

Tags: php, symfony, installation

I am new in Symfony 2. I am using Windows 8. I am trying to install Symfony 2. Location of my htodcs is `D:\php\htdocs`. Location of my Composer is `D:\php\php\composer.phar`. I am trying to install Symfony 2 using this command `D:\php\htdocs>php D:\php\php\composer.phar create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition my_symfony`. While this command is  executing I got the following message.

[image]

After executing that command I got following message in `CMD`.

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\php\php\ext\intl.so' -
The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\php\php\ext\intl.so' -
The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug true

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\php\php\ext\intl.so' -
The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
Trying to install assets as symbolic links.
Installing assets for Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle into web/bundles/framework
It looks like your system doesn't support relative symbolic links, so the assets
 were installed by using absolute symbolic links.
Installing assets for Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle into web/bundles/sensiodi
stribution
It looks like your system doesn't support relative symbolic links, so the assets
 were installed by using absolute symbolic links.
```

If I browse `http://localhost/my_symfony/web/app_dev.php`

Then I got following errors

[image]

[image]

Can anyone say what can be solution ??

Thanks

Comment: Have you still tried to create your own bundle with its route to see if it's working?

Comment: Actually, everything is working! Your intl error is related to your PHP setup - nothing to do with Symfony, though it would be nice to fix it. The screenshot shows that Symfony is working - this is Symfony's way of saying "Hi, everything is working, but there's no page configured here". You should be able to go to app_dev.php/app/example to see a page. Also, try the symfony demo: to get a great example application to learn from: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-demo

Comment: Thanks @weaverryan for your valuable reply. You are absolutely right. I suffered a lot with these. You saved me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason php can't access intl.so extension. It could be that the extension is installed but php don't have permission to access it or you should install it yourself. Piece of advice, Windows operating system is not really that popular when it comes to web development. It would be difficult for you to search for answers that can be applied in Windows and this applies to future problems as well. Develop using unix based operating systems.